# Parallel processing a Set

Tags: java, collections, parallel-processing

I have a `Set` of clients, and a `Event` I want to broadcast to them. To be more exact, I'm using `CopyOnWriteArraySet` to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`.

It's all working nicely, but I'm beginning to hit a performance issue with large number of clients.

Could you suggest a way to serve the clients in parallel?

The broadcast loop now looks basically like this:

```
for (Client client : clients) {
    sendTo(client, event);
}
```

Comment: Your problem probably lies in the implementation of sendTo() *or* you are hitting the network bandwidth limit.

Comment: It's all local, it's an event bus system. No network involved ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java 8, you can replace the loop with:

```
clients.parallelForEach(client -> sendTo(client, event));
```

With Java 7, you will need to manually write the code. A first simple version would look like:

```
private final ExecutorService executor = new FixedThreadPool(N_THREADS);

private void send(Set<Client> clients, final Event event) {
    for (Client client : clients) {
        final Client c = client;
        executor.submit(new Runnable() { public void run() { sendTo(c, event); }});
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Java 6, but maybe this will work too. Is it better than the other answer? (asking bcs it looks more complicated)

Comment: @MightyPork they are both the same thing: using an `ExecutorService` and invoking the method `sendTo` in `Runnable`s to make this work in parallel processing. The only difference is that assylias wrote the `Runnable` in a single line while I split it in different lines.

Comment: @MightyPork the 2 answers are doing the same thing really... Pick the one you find easier to understand.

Comment: Okay, but now I have a problem - it's kind of recursive, sendTo can - in some cases, invoke `send` on "child clients" (of DelegatingClient). It doesn't seem to work now :(

Comment: @MightyPork You may have a concurrency issue due to the send method not being thread safe or because the order of execution is changed.

Comment: Okay I think I'll work around that, Now.. does `invokeAll` block until all are finished, or somehow dispatch them in background?

Comment: @MightyPork No it returns immediately.

Comment: Um.. any ideas? `The method invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>) in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (List<Runnable>)`

Comment: @MightyPork My mistake - I just typed it without checking if it compiled. see edit in a minute.

Comment: Okay.. now it works, but it's like 100x slower than without the threading, so I think I'll just rollback it to what I had before.

Comment: Without knowing what sendTo does it is difficult to say much about what you observed...

Comment: oh well.. whatever. I'll give you a point for the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may use threads using [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Here's a kickoff example:

```
int MAX_THREADS = 10;
ExecutorSertive executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);
for (final Client client : clients) {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //if event is a variable or a parameter in the bigger method
            //mark it as final
            sentTo(client, event);
        }
    });
}
executor.shutdown();
```